# Bash replace in CSV multiple columns

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have the following CSV format:

```
data_disk01,"/opt=920MB;4512;4917;0;4855","/=4244MB;5723;6041;0;6359","/tmp=408MB;998;1053;0;1109","/var=789MB;1673;1766;0;1859","/boot=53MB;656;692;0;729"
```

I would like to take from each column, except the first one, the last value from the array, like this:

```
data_disk01,"/opt=4855","/=6359","/tmp=1109","/var=1859","/boot=729"
```

I have tried something like:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {if(NF==!1);gsub(/\=.*/,",")} 1'
```

Just the string, I managed to do it with:

```
string="/opt=920MB;4512;4917;0;4855"
echo $string | awk '{split($0,a,";"); print a[1],a[5]}' | sed 's#=.* #=#'
/opt=4855
```

But could not make it work for the whole CSV.
Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input never contains commas in the quoted fields, simple sed script should work:

```
sed 's/=[^"]*;/=/g' file.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following `awk` and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '{gsub(/=[^"]*;/,"=")} 1' Input_file
```

In case you want to save output into Input_file then append `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` in above code too.