# Bash select multiple values in CSV column

Tags: linux, bash, devops

I have the following CSV format:

`"/opt=920MB;4512;4917;0;4855","/=4244MB;5723;6041;0;6359","/tmp=408MB;998;1053;0;1109","/var=789MB;1673;1766;0;1859","/boot=53MB;656;692;0;729"`

I would like to extract 2 values from each column, the first and the last value from the array, after the "=", like this:

`"/opt=920MB;4855","/=4244MB;6359","/tmp=408MB;1109","/var=789MB;1859","/boot=53MB;729"`

Per column it can work like this:

```
echo "$string" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {split($0,a,";"); print a[1],a[5]}'
/opt=920MB;4855
```

Any hints are highly appreciated.

Comment: What's up with your previous question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/51250515/5291015. Didn't that work out?

Comment: This is different from that one, this is to get 2 values from each column, not only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution by using sed:

`echo "$string"| sed 's/=*;[^"]*;/,/g'`

Answer (score 0):

```
s/\([^;]*\);\([^;]*\)\[^"]*\([^;]*\);\([^;]*\)\[^"]*\([^;]*\);\([^;]*\)\[^"]*\([^;]*\);\([^;]*\)\[^"]*\([^;]*\);\([^;]*\)\[^"]*/\1;\2;\3;\4;\5;\6;\7;\8;\9;\10/
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. While this answer might be amazing, could you please elaborate on it and explain a bit why this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without sed that way :

```
xargs -d"\"" -n 1 -a file.csv | xargs -d";" | awk '/ key (start|stop) / {next} {if (match($0,"/")) printf("\"%s;%s\",",$1,$NF)} END {print ""}' |  rev | cut -c 2- | rev
```